# JavaScript - String.split() but for Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, data-manipulation

Let's say I have this array of strings (they're HTML elements, but we can use strings to keep it simple):

```
["something", "else", "and", "d", "more", "things", "in", "the", "d", "array", "etc"]
```

I need a quick way to split this array up by `"d"`. Kinda like `String.split()`, except for arrays. The end result should be something like this:

```
[["something", "else", "and"], ["more", "things", "in", "the"], ["array", "etc"]]
```

Are there any simple one-liners for this? Maybe there's a function built into JS and I'm just missing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if it's a one-liner you want, here you go:

```js
var myArray = ["something", "else", "and", "d", "more", "things", "in", "the", "d", "array", "etc"];

const result = myArray.reduce((a, c) => c === "d" ? (a.arr[++a.i] = []) && a : a.arr[a.i].push(c) && a, {arr: [[]], i: 0}).arr;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yep that's a one-liner ;) heh.  I am guessing OP was looking for a native method (different version of *split*) or method for binning for arrays, given a delimiter.

Comment: @vol7ron Ye I think so as well. Though unfortunetely there isn't, so something like this will have to do if you want a one-liner haha

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to join by spaces, then split by `' d '`, then split each subarray by spaces:

```js
const input = ["something", "else", "and", "d", "more", "things", "in", "the", "d", "array", "etc"];
const output = input
  .join(' ')
  .split(' d ')
  .map(str => str.split(' '));
console.log(output);
```

Or, without joining, figure out the index of every `d`, and `slice` every section of the input around the `d`s:

```js
const input = ["something", "else", "and", "d", "more", "things", "in", "the", "d", "array", "etc"];
const dIndicies = input.reduce((a, item, i) => {
  if (item === 'd') a.push(i);
  return a;
}, []);
const output = dIndicies.reduce((a, dIndex, i, arr) => {
  const nextDIndex = arr[i + 1];
  a.push(input.slice(dIndex + 1, nextDIndex));
  return a;
}, [input.slice(0, dIndicies[0] - 1)]);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I hope OP doesn't intend for there to be spaces in any of the strings... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce starting with an accumulator that has an array containing an empty array. If the current item is the split value add an extra empty array to the end, otherwise spread the last array with the current item.

```js
const arr = ["something", "else", "and", "d", "more", "things", "in", "the", "d", "array", "etc"];

const splitArray = (array, val) =>
  array && array.length
    ? array.reduce(
        (results, item) =>
          item === val
            ? [...results, []]
            : [...results.filter((_, i) => i < results.length - 1), [...results[results.length - 1], item]],
        [[]]
      )
    : array;
  
  
console.log(splitArray(arr, 'd'));
```

Comment: It a little funky if the array starts or end in "d".

Comment: Not really, it works the same as string split as ',abc'.split(',') will give ['', 'abc'] so I am happy with it giving an empty array if the array starts with the split value.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let myArray = ["something", "else", "and", "d", "more", "things", "in", "the", "d", "array", "etc"];
let splitArray = [],
    tempArray = [];
myArray.forEach((ele, index) => {
    if(ele !== 'd') {
      tempArray.push(ele);
    }
    if(ele === 'd' || index === myArray.length - 1) {
      splitArray.push(tempArray);
      tempArray = []; 
    }
})

console.log(': ', splitArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `forEach` approach is enough.

```js
var arr = ["something", "else", "and", "d", "more", "things", "in", "the", "d", "array", "etc"];
var result = [], temp = [];

arr.forEach(function(elem, index){
    elem !=='d' ? temp.push(elem) : (result.push(temp), temp = []);
    index==arr.length-1 && (result.push(temp));
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, there aren't any concise one-liners that come to mind, but you may accomplish what you want with just a few lines of code by iterating over your values and if the word isn't `'d'` store it; if it is, then create a new array to hold the next non-'d' value:

```js
const words = ["something", "else", "and", "d", "more", "things", "in", "the", "d", "array", "etc"]

let grouped = words.reduce((response,word)=>{
  if (word!=='d')
    response[response.length-1].push(word)
  else
    response[response.length]=[]
  return response
},[[]])

console.log(grouped)
```

Comment: Gave a one-liner solution for this. It's unreadable like crazy, but it works, lol

Answer (score 1):

You can make a pretty elegant recursive function with something like:

```js
let arr = ["something", "else", "and", "d", "more", "things", "in", "the", "d", "array", "etc"]

const spliton = (v, arr, i = arr.indexOf(v)) => (i < 0) 
    ? [arr]
    : [arr.slice(0, i), ...spliton(v, arr.slice(i+1))]


console.log(spliton('d', arr))
```

Comment: Honestly, OP should remove the accepted mark from my answer and make this one the accepted answer. It's technically a re-usable one-liner that's much, much more readable as well! +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional encoding that works for any [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) input (including arrays)

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const prepend = (xs, x) =>
 [ x ] .concat (xs)

const split = (f, [ x = None, ...xs ], then = prepend) =>
  x === None
    ? then ([], [])
    : split
        ( f
        , xs
        , (l, r) =>
            f (x)
              ? then (prepend (l, r), [])
              : then (l, prepend (r, x))
        )

const data = 
  [ 'something', 'else', 'and', 'd', 'more', 'things', 'in', 'the', 'd', 'array', 'etc' ]

console .log
  ( split (x => x === 'd', data)
  )

// [ [ 'something', 'else', 'and' ]
// , [ 'more', 'things', 'in', 'the' ]
// , [ 'array', 'etc' ]
// ]
```

And an optimization that works for any [array-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects) input

```
const prepend = (xs, x) =>
 [ x ] .concat (xs)

const split = (f, xs = [], i = 0, then = prepend) =>
  i >= xs.length
    ? then ([], [])
    : split
        ( f
        , xs
        , i + 1
        , (l, r) =>
            f (xs[i])
              ? then (prepend (l, r), [])
              : then (l, prepend (r, xs[i]))
        )

const data = 
  [ 'something', 'else', 'and', 'd', 'more', 'things', 'in', 'the', 'd', 'array', 'etc' ]

console .log
  ( split (x => x === 'd', data)
  )

// [ [ 'something', 'else', 'and' ]
// , [ 'more', 'things', 'in', 'the' ]
// , [ 'array', 'etc' ]
// ]
```

Both implementations are *O(n)*.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about **mutating** the array this is also pretty trivial with `while` and [`Array.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift):

```js
let r = [[]], data = ["something", "else", "and", "d", "more", "things", "in", "the", "d", "array", "etc"]

while(data.length) {
  let item = data.shift()
  item != 'd' ? r[r.length-1].push(item) : r.push([]) 
}

console.log(r)
```

And if you do then even shorter with [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let arr = ["something", "else", "and", "d", "more", "things", "in", "the", "d", "array", "etc"]

let f = arr.reduce((r,c) => (c!='d' ? r[r.length-1].push(c) : r.push([]),r),[[]])

console.log(f)
```

The idea in both is to start with `[[]]` and then the only check you need is if the current element of the iteration is `d` and if so push new array or push to `r[r.length-1]` which is the previous `sub array`.